# Angularjs ng-repeate display only last value

Tags: angularjs

```
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-repeat="_Routevalue in _ViewItems">
        <!--<li><a>Hello</a></li>-->
        <!--<li><a>Hello</a></li>-->
        <li>{{_Routevalue.productName}}</li>
    </ul>
```

Here's the hardcoded values displayed properly, but when I use the `ng-repeat` it's only showing the last one.

Answer (score 2):

You should add ng-repeat to the `<li>`, not to the `<ul>`

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li ng-repeat="_Routevalue in _ViewItems">{{_Routevalue.productName}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: While this is 100% correct, i'm not sure if this is the issue.   This would still show all values, just each one within its own `<ul>`. Unless there is a CSS style that is doing a float / position on them and they're really just stacking.

Comment: Ok, so what is the value of _ViewItems? is it an Array or an Object?

Comment: @MichaelLynch   <li style="padding: 5px;" ng-repeat="_Routevalue in _ViewItems">
                             <a class="_Routevalue.menuIcon">  {{_Routevalue.productName}}</a>
                         </li>  here class="_Routevalue.menuIcon"  is not binding menu icons

Comment: I mean, the value of _ViewItems in the controller, you can try with ```console.log($scope._ViewItems)```

Comment: @susSam Did the answer above solve your problem (as you're now asking about a class issue?).   To solve your class problem, instead of `class="_Routevalue.menuIcon"` use `ng-class="_Routevalue.menuIcon"`